# 3 finger multitouch - Lenovo E530

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

i have started to try out some more from Ubuntu as dualboot on my laptop (Lenovo E530 with 640M). In Windows my touchpads gestures are working with three fingers to emulate back and forward (in a browser for example) which is awesome. In Ubuntu I can use multitouch to scroll with two fingers both vertically and horizontal but gestures with more fingers aren’t working at all.

I’ve got Nvidia Optimus working, my battery time, but I’m totally stuck at this.
According to this link (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/l...-laptop-review) they aren’t having some problems with multitouch. The questing is if they are just counting two-finger scroll.

Anyway, Ubuntu has on their website (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch) a guide how multitouch should work. And they also says that I just need to enable two-finger multitouch, the rest should work out-of-the box. If it’s working at all.

Anyone got some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/931171. I think we should wait till this fixed.